# Ruby, Generate a random hex color

Tags: ruby

How can I generate a random hex color with ruby?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One-liner with `unpack`:
`Random.new.bytes(3).unpack("H*")[0]`

Since ruby 2.6.0 you can do it even shorter: 
`Random.bytes(3).unpack1('H*')`

Comment: Love this: `Random.bytes(3).unpack1('H*')`

Answer (score 150):

Here's one way:

```
colour = "%06x" % (rand * 0xffffff)
```

Comment: Could someone explain it (especially the "%06x"?

Comment: The [% method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-25) on String uses the string as a format specification for the argument. "%06x" means: format a number as hex, 6 characters (digits in this case) wide, 0 padded.

Comment: @jeremy-ruten, I had to move the accepted answer over to airled's answer, please fogive me ;)

Answer (score 40):

```
SecureRandom.hex(3)
#=> "fef912"
```

The `SecureRandom` module is part of Ruby's standard library

```
require 'securerandom'
```

It's autoloaded in Rails, but if you're using Rails 3.0 or lower, you'll need to use

```
ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.hex(3)
```

Comment: If you are going to use this option, you will need to prepend the hex with "#". Works great, just don't forget the hash symbol at the beginning.

Answer (score 12):

You can generate each component independently:

```
r = rand(255).to_s(16)
g = rand(255).to_s(16)
b = rand(255).to_s(16)

r, g, b = [r, g, b].map { |s| if s.size == 1 then '0' + s else s end }

color = r + g + b      # => e.g. "09f5ab"
```

Comment: This is considerably more customizable, but Jeremy's solution is much much more concise.

Comment: For arbitrary byte length (replace 3 w/ number of bytes): `"".tap {|s| 3.times {s << ("%02x" % rand(255))}}`

Comment: but this is still a cool way to do it, thumbs up for readability.

Comment: You should change to `rand(256)`, since this current method will limit the lightest color to `#fefefe` (highest value `rand(255)` can output is 254).

Answer (score 2):

also you can do this:

```
colour = '#%X%X%X' % 3.times.map{ rand(255) }
```

> some updates:

or if you want to freeze any color:

```
class RandomColor
  def self.get_random
    rand(255)
  end

  def self.color_hex(options = {})
    default = { red: get_random, green: get_random, blue: get_random }
    options = default.merge(options)
    '#%X%X%X' % options.values
  end
end
```

then

```
# full random colour

RandomColor.color_hex() => #299D3D
RandomColor.color_hex() => #C0E92D

# freeze any colour

RandomColor.color_hex(red: 100) => #644BD6
RandomColor.color_hex(red: 100) => #6488D9
```