# Ruby shortest way to write rnd hex

Tags: ruby

What I have is a method used to generate random hex values. E.g `666` or `FF7`

However, I don't think it looks simple/elegant at all.. What I want is to make it **more simple** which perhaps will make my code shorter as well, but I don't know how. That is why I need tips or hints

Here is my code so far:

```
def random_values
random_values = Array.new
letters = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
for i in 1..15
  if i <= 9
    random_values << i
  else
    random_values << letters[i-10]
  end
end  
return random_values.shuffle[0].to_s + random_values.shuffle[0].to_s + random_values.shuffle[0].to_s
end
```

As you probably see, I do not generate random numbers. I just shuffle the array containing the values I want, meaning all the numbers in the array are unique, which is not needed, but was the easiest solution for me when I wrote the code.

I am most concerned about the **return line**.. If only it was possible to write like:

```
return 3.times { random_values.shuffle[0] }
```

or

`return random_values.shuffle[0].to_s *3`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Regarding your last comment, you can do something like (1..3).map{ some_code }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def random_value
     r = Random.new
     ((r.rand * 16)).to_i.to_s(16)
end

puts random_value + random_value + random_value
```

Or, after some quick research:

```
"%06x" % (rand * 0xffffff)
```

From [Ruby, Generate a random hex color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698318/ruby-generate-a-random-hex-color)

Also, you shouldn't be looking for a more *efficient* solution per se. You seem to be looking for something more elegant, simple, and intuitive. (My solution is none of these, by the way. The searched one is.)

Comment: This is much sexier! Thanks! And you are probably right, a more simple solution was what I was looking for.

Comment: Sexier... I think that's a wonderful synonym for elegance. I'm sure it was the first thing Dijkstra blurted when he discovered the Shortest Path algorithm.

Comment: `rand` takes an integer value, allowing the command to be a bit simpler: `'%06x' % rand(0xffffff)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
# For Ruby 1.9
require 'securerandom'
SecureRandom.hex(16)

# For Ruby 1.8 and above
require 'active_support/secure_random'
ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.hex(16)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
(rand * MAX_VALUE).to_i.to_s(16)
```

Where MAX_VALUE is the upper bound for the numbers. You can also add some lower bound:

```
(MIN_VALUE + rand * (MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE)).to_i.to_s(16)
```

This will give you numbers in the range [MIN_VALUE,MAX_VALUE)