# Ruby, Generate a random hex color (only light colors)

Tags: ruby, random, colors

I know this is possible duplicated question. 
[Ruby, Generate a random hex color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698318/ruby-generate-a-random-hex-color)

My question is slightly different. I need to know, how to generate the random hex light colors only, not the dark.

Comment: Where do you draw the line between dark and light colors?

Comment: @Jonas Why would this matter for a solution?

Comment: No, i'm not using this for drawing. I would display the light colors in my project but it should show the different color every page refresh.

Comment: Just like @Alin wrote below it depends on how you define a light color. Maybe it's that the sum of r, g, b should be at least 0xff and one of them at least 0x80, maybe it's something else.

Comment: @Jonas Elfström You define a light color as having `L (lightness) > 0.5`. So there is an official definition for lightness, but it's not directly related to RGB.

Comment: Here's the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800044/ruby-color-generator/3800345#3800345

Comment: Also check out http://color.rubyforge.org/

Comment: @Jonas It seems you found a duplicate :)

Comment: @Alin Kind of, but the question doesn't mention brightness as a paramater even though the answer has one.

Comment: @Jonas I saw that, but I think it still counts as a duplicate if the answer is sufficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[In this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596216/formula-to-determine-brightness-of-rgb-color) colour lumincance is described with a formula of

```
(0.2126*r) + (0.7152*g) + (0.0722*b)
```

The same formula for luminance is [given in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminance_(relative)) (and it is taken from [this publication](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/Color/sRGB)). It reflects the human perception, with green being the most "intensive" and blue the least.

Therefore, you can select r, g, b until the luminance value goes above the division between *light* and *dark* (255 to 0). For example:

```
lum, ary = 0, []
while lum < 128
 ary = (1..3).collect {rand(256)}
 lum = ary[0]*0.2126 + ary[1]*0.7152 + ary[2]*0.0722
end
```

[Another article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brightness) refers to brightness, being the arithmetic mean of r, g and b. Note that brightness is even more subjective, as *a given target luminance can elicit different perceptions of brightness in different contexts* (in particular, the surrounding colours can affect your perception).

All in all, it depends on which colours you consider "light".

Comment: So, you want to say that #FF0000 is not light? Or #FF7777 for that matter? I don't think the RGB model is suitable for this.

Comment: @Alin You are right. That is why the answer started with "depends how you define *light*". I hope now it makes more sense and is a little more precise.

Comment: Your answer is "close enough" now. You may want to add some links to (original) sources that define "lightness" using that formula.

Answer (score 3):

Just some pointers:

Use [HSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) and generate the individual values randomly, but keeping L in the interval of your choosing. Then [convert to RGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#From_HSL), if needed.

It's a bit harder than generating RGB with all components over a certain value (say 0x7f), but this is the way to go if you want the colors distributed evenly.

Answer (score 2):

-- I found that 128 to 256 gives the lighter colors

```
    Dim rand As New Random
    Dim col As Color
    col = Color.FromArgb(rand.Next(128, 256), rand.Next(128, 256), rand.Next(128, 256))
```

Answer (score 1):

All colors where each of r, g ,b is greater than 0x7f

```
color = (0..2).map{"%0x" % (rand * 0x80 + 0x80)}.join
```

Comment: It shows the eight characters (alphanumeric). but, the hex color is six only, right?. irb(main):001:0> color = (0..3).map{"%0x" % (rand * 0x80 + 0x7f)}.join
=> "e1ad8f97"
irb(main):002:0> color = (0..3).map{"%0x" % (rand * 0x80 + 0x7f)}.join
=> "d28cf5fe"
irb(main):003:0>

Answer (score 1):

I modified one of the answers from the linked question ([Daniel Spiewak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1698336/293635)) to come up with something that is pretty flexible in terms of excluding darker colors:

```
floor = 22 # meaning darkest possible color is #222222
r = (rand(256-floor) + floor).to_s 16
g = (rand(256-floor) + floor).to_s 16
b = (rand(256-floor) + floor).to_s 16

[r,g,b].map {|h| h.rjust 2, '0'}.join
```

You can change the `floor` value to suit your needs. A higher value will limit the output to lighter colors, and a lower value will allow darker colors.

Comment: Super easy to use.  I modified the floor to 150 to make sure all colors look good as a background for black text.

Answer (score 0):

A really nice solution is provided by the [color-generator gem](https://github.com/jpmckinney/color-generator), where you can call:

```
ColorGenerator.new(saturation: 0.75, lightness: 0.5).create_hex
```