# Random function return only some of the possible colors

Tags: php, random, hex

I have a php function that generates a random color, but I need to truncate it so it only returns the light colors (so text can contrast more easily), how can I do this? I have trouble thinking it in Hex to make the comparisons. Here's my function:

```
function randomColor() {
    $str = '#';
    for($i = 0 ; $i < 6 ; $i++) {
        $randNum = rand(0 , 15);
        switch ($randNum) {
            case 10: $randNum = 'A'; break;
            case 11: $randNum = 'B'; break;
            case 12: $randNum = 'C'; break;
            case 13: $randNum = 'D'; break;
            case 14: $randNum = 'E'; break;
            case 15: $randNum = 'F'; break;
        }
        $str .= $randNum;
    }
    return $str;
}
$color = randomColor();
```

Comment: Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187738/ruby-generate-a-random-hex-color-only-light-colors can help you out.

Answer (score 6):

Light colors have higher values in hex (#FFFFFF = white).

You would be much better generating the colours in threes, rather than 6 individual parts so you generate a red, green and blue component. Also, you can use `dechex()` to convert from decimal to hex and get rid of that ugly `switch` structure.

You can just set a minimum value in your `rand()` higher than 0 for the lighter colors, or equally make the maximum lower to make it darker.

```
function randomColor ($minVal = 0, $maxVal = 255)
{

    // Make sure the parameters will result in valid colours
    $minVal = $minVal < 0 || $minVal > 255 ? 0 : $minVal;
    $maxVal = $maxVal < 0 || $maxVal > 255 ? 255 : $maxVal;

    // Generate 3 values
    $r = mt_rand($minVal, $maxVal);
    $g = mt_rand($minVal, $maxVal);
    $b = mt_rand($minVal, $maxVal);

    // Return a hex colour ID string
    return sprintf('#%02X%02X%02X', $r, $g, $b);

}
```

So you can call e.g. `randomColor(150,255)` to get a lighter colour or  `randomColor(0,100)` to get a darker colour.

Answer (score 1):

0xAA == 170 so you can pick a random number between 170 and 255 and convert it to hexadecimal.

```
function randomColor() {
    $str = '#';
    for($i = 0 ; $i < 3 ; $i++) {
        $str .= dechex( rand(170 , 255) );
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: @George Based on the OP's question it seems likely that he's ok with a limited set of light colors. Having a random color from all possible light colors available in the RGB palette is probably not the goal here. (Ok, the comment I was responding to has been deleted but I guess I'll leave this here anyway.)

Answer (score -1):

```
function rand_color() {
$string = '';
for($x = 1; $x <= 6; $x++){
$string .= substr(str_shuffle('89abcdef'),1,1);
}
return $string;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.