# How do I generate a random hex code that of a lighter color in javascript?

Tags: javascript, hex

I am using a random color for the background, but since the text is black, when really dark colors are generated, the text can't be seen. How do I exclude these dark colors when generating the hexadecimal code?

I could only figure out how to get this:

`Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)`

But this does not exclude dark colors. Could someone please help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Using alpha could be one way.

Comment: Something that might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187738/ruby-generate-a-random-hex-color-only-light-colors

Comment: This one too, it's almost what you want (remove 0 to 8, for example) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator-in-javascript

Comment: You could use a bitwise OR to ensure some of the high bits are always set. Something like `c = (Math.floor(Math.random()*0xffffff)|0x0f0f0f).toString(16);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do is generate a number from 00 to FF for each (RGB) (ie `000000` to `FFFFFF`).  I would also make sure the G value is approximately higher than 33.

Comment: Thanks! I just used this code instead: 

`(Math.floor((Math.random()*222)+33).toString(16))+(Math.floor((Math.random()*222)+33).toString(16))+(Math.floor((Math.random()*222)+33).toString(16))` Really dark colors are no longer generated... Thank you!

Comment: @areke I think your code produces from decimal 33 to 254. And decimal 33 is 21 HEX. (meaning that you can get `#212121` which is pretty dark, it is darker than the text-color of comments here in SO)

Comment: 33 hex is 51 decimal. So just change it to 51 if you are using decimal values.

Comment: @KingKongFrog 33 hex is too low, even 99 hex (or 153 decimal) is very dark, just look [how dark they are](http://jsfiddle.net/tWyq6/3/)

Answer (score 9):

The higher the values, the lighter the color will be, you can try to add a random value to a high number (`200` in this case):

```
var randValue = Math.floor(Math.random()*56)+200; //200 to 255
```

**Note:** the maximum HEX value is `FF` which equals to decimal `255`

Then, you can optionally convert these RBG values to HEX using `.toString(16)`, but as far as I know, you can set colors using RBG values.

Here is a **[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tWyq6/4/)**

Comment: Accepted answer generates dark colours. This one works perfect. Thanks you VU

Answer (score 3):

random RGB without the numbers 1 & 2, so you get nice colors, done with less code:

```
var randomColor = (function lol(m, s, c) {
                    return s[m.floor(m.random() * s.length)] +
                        (c && lol(m, s, c - 1));
                })(Math, '3456789ABCDEF', 4);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tWyq6/27/) Demo

Comment: Not bad, though I think some of the colors are still too dark. I'd try it only with `ABCDEF`.